# PHP select data from previous 24 hours sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, datetime

I was using the script below to pull data from previous 24hrs and spit it out in a html table, it worked for the whole month of August but then messed up since the month changed to September and is now displaying all data from first entry..

My 'Timestamp' column is varchar + primary key and is formatted like so: 04/09/2014 01:33:59

This is the script:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM my_table
        WHERE Timestamp >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y') 
        ORDER BY Timestamp ";
```

What is wrong with this script? I just want it to pull all data from the past 24 hours and that is all, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using a `DATETIME` datatype for the Timestamp column? Dates in that format can't be compared easily.

Comment: If you're going to store it as a VARCHAR, you should use `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: shot in the dark but would `WHERE Timestamp LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')` work? Instead of getting anything after just get all the ones matching. Im not even sure this is valid sql

Comment: Barmar, Because the format I need it to be display as is DD/MM/YYYY it's the standard format here in Ireland... We find it easier to read and looks neater :)

Comment: You should use formatting functions when displaying to the user, it shouldn't affect how you store in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting `CURDATE()` to a string, you should convert `Timestamp` to a `DATE`. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for this.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

You could also use your original query, but just use `=` instead of `>=`. You just want rows from the current date, not rows in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If in PHP, i use `diff`

```
$sql = "SELECT timestamp from yourtable";
$now = new DateTime();
if($r = mysql_query($sql))
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
   {
      $dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row['timestamp']));
      $dates = new DateTime($dt);
      $datedif = $now->diff($dates)->format("%d");
      if($datedif >= 1)
      {
           Your events
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you